# Django dynamically create not equal q objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-q

I'm working on creating dynamic filters using nested AND / OR logic, and would like to include NOT as an option. This leverages Q objects to create the nested AND / OR logic.

The class takes in a json object like so:

```
filters = {
    'and': {
        "url__is": "www.test.com",
        "name__is": "test"
    }
}
```

This gets compiled down to

```
.filter(Q(url__is='www.test.com') and Q(name__is='test')
```

This works via a recursive function that really just does this on each level of the json tree.

```
return source_queryset.filter(reduce(and_, filter_list))
```

and_ is from the python operator library and has been working great. I'd like to add NOT as an option as well though, and can't seem to find an equivalent option to reduce a list of Q objects to.

Does anyone know a way to use reduce in a way that creates the idea of not equal to a list of q objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `~` operator on a `Q` object, which is a [complex lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

In the end you would have something like this:

```
.filter(~Q(url__is='www.test.com'))
```

To match your recursive function you should use the [`inv` or `invert`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.inv) operator. Because it matches the desired output when using `~` operator.

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> from operator import inv
>>> ~Q()
<Q: (NOT (AND: ))>
>>> inv(Q())
<Q: (NOT (AND: ))>
```

So you can use it in your recursive function with something like this:

```
return source_queryset.filter(map(inv, filter_list))
```

Comment: Using reduce() with inv() throws the following error: inv() takes exactly one argument (2 given). Any thought on a work around for that? @bernardo

Comment: @Khakis7 What are the parameters that you're using? (What is the value of filter_list?)

Comment: @Khakis7 Sorry for that. Since `~` is an unary operator, you have to use `map` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: @Khakis7 If you intend to use `and` after `~` you can simply do the following: `source_queryset.filter(recude(and_, map(inv, filter_list)))`

Comment: it seems to be creating a very weird result set using map '(NOT (AND: (NOT (AND: ('item_id', 'random string'))), (NOT (AND: ('url', 'https://google.com/')))))'

Comment: @Khakis7 Can you share a input with a desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can flip any Q object by applying the `~` operator in front of it.

```
.exclude(Q(id=5))
```

is the same as:

```
.filter(~Q(id=5))
```

You should be able to use this when calculating `filter_list`.